# How to show the "Home" folder for SSRS 2008 in SQL Management Studio

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssms

Our Sys Admin just installed SSRS 2008 for me to play around with and see if I can get all our 2005 projects running on it. However, when I log onto the report server with SQL Management Studio 2008 there is no "Home" folder listed in Object Explorer.  With our SSRS 2005 server I get a Home folder that contains a list of all our reports and lets me create subscriptions and edit properties on reports. The Sys Admin doesn't know why the Home folder isn't there and I'm wondering if anyone here does. We can successfully view and run reports if I go to the /Reports URL for our report server in a web browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Breaking Changes in SQL Server Reporting Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143380.aspx)

> In Management Studio, the Home folder is removed in this release. You cannot view, manage, distribute or secure report server content in Management Studio.

To access the functionality the Home folder provided, go to the URL defined under section Report Manager URL in Reporting Services Configuration Manager.

Answer (score 1):

By default only the BUILTIN\Administrators has access to the HOME page. Ask your administrator to grant you permissions on the properties of the Home Folder